# how to programetically get the type (TemplateType) of a Library using the item url

Tags: document-library, object-model, picture-library

Imagine if you have image url which is existing within a site collection in `Sitecollectionimages` library: `testserver/Sitecollectionimages/image.jpg`

How can I get the [TemplateType](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.se/2008/01/sharepoint-registrationid-list-template.html) (which kind of library is this for e.g. `Type 109` is for Picture Library) of this library using the image url?

Update: I will always have an absolute URL of the image.

Comment: Is this image url an absolute url?

Comment: why dont use, SP solution generator and see the lists and document library associated to that specific site/sitecollection :)

Comment: Matthias, it will always be be an absolute url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(<siteUrl>)
{
  using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
  {
    SPList list = web.GetList(<imageUrl>);
    SPListTemplateType templateType = list.BaseTemplate;       
    int templateTypeInt = (int) templateType;
  }
}
```

Comment: Mathias, will it work for absolute url?

Comment: will it work for image url like this ? testserver/Sitecollectionimages/image.jpg

Comment: +1, it should work as expected